# Perl recursion causing "use of uninitialized value" error

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, and can't seem to find answers about this anywhere. I narrowed down the problem to a recursive function. If I comment that out, then it works just fine without errors. I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

 sub GeneratePermutations{
    my($n, $nMax, $i, $ArrLength, @Arr) = @_;

    if($n == 0){
    foreach($i..$ArrLength-1){
        $Arr[$i] = 0;
        ++$i;
    }

    my @qArr = ();
    my $rVal = 1; 
    for(my $p = 0; $p < @Arr; $p++){

        $rVal *= fac($Arr[$p]);

        for(my $q = 0; $q < $ArrLength; $q++){

        my $qCount = 0; 
        for(my $j = 0; $j < $ArrLength; $j++){ 

            if($Arr[$j] eq $q){
            ++$qCount;
            }


        }
        $qArr[$i] = $qCount;
        }
    }
    my $qVal = 1;
    for(my $qNum = 0; $qNum < @qArr; $qNum++){
        $qVal *= fac($qArr[$qNum]);
    }
    my $maxDistVal = 0;
    $maxDistVal = (1/($ArrLength**$ArrLength))*(fac($ArrLength)/$rVal)*(fac($ArrLength)/$qVal);

    if($maxDistVal > $distribution){
        $distribution = $maxDistVal;
    }
    #prints out distributions for all permutations (comment out previous if-statement)
    print "Dist: " . $distribution . "<br /><br />";
    #return 1;
    }
    my $resultCnt = 0;
    for(my $cnt = MinVal($nMax, $n); $cnt > 0; $cnt--){
    $Arr[$i] = $cnt;
    ++$resultCnt; 
    GeneratePermutations(int($n-$cnt), $cnt, $i+1, $ArrLength, @Arr);
    }

    #return $resultCnt;
    return $distribution;

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. And we could help find where it's coming from if you post the full warning message, you know--the one that includes the operation (comparison, etc) and line number.

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma, I'm sure you mean "It's a warning, and it may not indicate an error", although it usually does.

Comment: I don't get this warning, I get: `Global symbol "$distribution" requires explicit package name at x.pl line 40.
Global symbol "$distribution" requires explicit package name at x.pl line 41.
Global symbol "$distribution" requires explicit package name at x.pl line 44.
Global symbol "$distribution" requires explicit package name at x.pl line 55.
Execution of x.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: `use of uninitialized value` could refer to a great many things in this script. You need to check the line number, and what kind of statement it is, e.g. `use of uninitialized value in multiplication`. As it is, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Hi, the full warning I get is:
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in numeric gt (>) at ./distribution.pl line 239.
This line actually refers to a different function altogether, but that function didn't have problems when I comment out the code above.

I should add - the error is pointing to this:

$_[0]>1?$_[0]*fac($_[0]-1):1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to comment out parts of my code and found that if I remove this portion, then the warnings disappear:

```
for(my $qNum = 0; $qNum < @qArr; $qNum++){
    $qVal *= fac($qArr[$qNum]);
}
```

Comment: Exactly. $qArr[$#qArr] (or the last element of @qArr) is defined, but the rest of the array is undefined. So some iterations of this for loop are going to attempt to call fac(undef), which will result in a warning.  
As I said in my answer above, there's a loop that looks like it might be intended to set all the elements in @qArr, but it only sets one of them.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how? My first loop right after the if($n==0) sets the rest of the array elements to 0. When I do a print command, it prints out all of the arrays correctly. e.g. if n=5, I get: [5][0][0][0][0], [4][1][0][0][0], etc.

Comment: In the first loop you set the elements of $Arr[$i..$ArrLength-1] to 0 (not `@qArr`, but `@Arr`). That loop also increases $i, so after it executes, $i will be equal to $ArrLength (Incidentally, this is a strange way to use foreach). After that, you declare `@qArr` as a new, empty array, and only set one element, $qArr[$i]. So for example if $i is 3, `@qArr` will contain (undef, undef, undef, $qCount).

Comment: I see. Okay thanks! I'm not the best coder, so this might be a convoluted way to do it, but it's the only way I can figure out how to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I would say this is the problem: `$qArr[$i] = $qCount;`

Because you're only writing one element in @qArr repeatedly, and then later on reading elements 0 through $#qArr.

Did you mean `$qArr[$p] = $qCount;`? Or `$qArr[$q] = $qCount;`?

Answer (score 0):

When You declare $distribution it will probably have to be outside of the subroutine as you need it to persist throughout the recursion.